# Maya python commands to Maya api: modelEditor settings

Tags: python, api, maya

I'm trying to switch active 3d view with desired settings on while using the python API instead of the Maya python commands. Which API functions should I use?

**Python command gives me the desired result:**

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

editor = 'modelPanel4'
cmds.modelEditor(editor, edit=True, displayAppearance='smoothShaded', nurbsCurves=True, nurbsSurfaces=True, polymeshes=True, textures=True, useDefaultMaterial=False, backfaceCulling=False, displayTextures=True, grid=False)
```

**I am trying to get the same result using the Maya Python API but cannot find the suitable functions.**

```
import maya.OpenMayaUI as omui

view = omui.M3dView.active3dView()
#displObj = view.objectDisplay()
view.setObjectDisplay(7)
#displStyle = view.displayStyle()
view.setDisplayStyle(2)
#displTexMode = view.textureMode()
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: you might find an answer to this on, not a lot of maya api guy on stack : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/python_inside_maya

Comment: _____Thanks a lot_____

Answer (score 0):

Just use the python code you started with. Historically Maya has always been designed with a very clear separation:

- The GUI is written in MEL (although you can do that in python now)
- The computation of a node (and GL rendering) is written in C++ (or the python API)

If you are hoping that you can find an API equivalent for a GUI method, you are out of luck. There are a few GUI classes within the API, but they are specifically there to help add custom GUI tools and manipulators. They aren't there to help manipulate the existing GUI, for that you'll need to use the python (or MEL) commands as you did in the first code snippet.